# Multiple options from array build regex

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string

I have the following data structure:

```
var suffixes = ["example", "document", "service", ...];
```

I want to scan a directory and take only the files with a given filename structure: `[0-9a-zA-Z]*\.<a suffix>.txt` where `<a suffix>` can match any of these suffixes.

What's the best way to test for this regex? Can I build a regex from a string array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var suffix = 'example';
var string = ' directory name ';

string.match(new RegExp('[0-9a-zA-Z]*\.' + suffix + '.txt'))
```

or

```
var suffixes = ["example", "document", "service"].join('|')
string.match(new RegExp('[0-9a-zA-Z]*\.(' + suffixes + ').txt'))
```

Comment: Note, all suffixes shall not contain special characters, such as `+[]{}()*?^$|\.`, for this solution to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can build something like

```
[0-9a-zA-Z]*\.(example|document|service)\.txt
```

However, I don't think this will look very readable. I would consider avoiding regex in this case in order to make the code more straighforward.

Comment: What I meant is how to build that matcher programatically, see +Alexander's answer. If you have any answer that doesn't involve regexes please post it.